# Initialising shared_ptr , when the object requires a default constructor

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, lemon-graph-library

For assigning shared_ptr to a Graph type variable in lemon graph library i did this:

```
typedef ListDigraph Graph;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Graph> Process_pointer;
Process_pointer process(new Graph);
```

It worked fine, but now i need to declare a shared_ptr for a map object, Normally the map object works like this :

```
Graph process;
typedef ListDigraph::NodeMap<string> Node_names;
Node_names name(process);
```

That is, name requires a Graph object for its default constructor.

For declaring a shared_ptr for it, i did this:

```
typedef ListDigraph::NodeMap<string> Node_names;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Node_names> Nname_pointer;
Nname_pointer name = new Node_names;
name(process);
```

I know, the declaration for name is wrong, but how do i assign it memory as well as initialise it with process object.

Comment: You mean like [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

```
auto p = std::make_shared<Node_names>(process);
```

This works for types with constructors with an arbitrary number of parameters.

Note that this is the recommended default way to create `shared_ptr`s with managed objects. See [**Why should you almost always use make_shared to create an object to be owned by shared_ptrs?**](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/).

Answer (score 3):

```
Nname_pointer name (new Node_names (process));
```

Remark: This has nothing to do with shared_ptr, it would be the same with a regular pointer.

Comment: This works with more than one argument, too. new Node_names (process, 1, true, "Hello");