# Is there a way to automatically initialize a std::shared_ptr to hold a valid object?

Tags: c++, constructor, std, shared-ptr

When I write

```
std::shared_ptr<MyType> x;
```

x is initialized with an empty shared pointer to a nullptr. But I would like it to automatically call the default (or some other designated constructor) of MyType. I know, that I could just write:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyType> x = std::maked_shared<MyTYpe>();
```

but sometimes people forget and then you run into trouble, so enforcing this by the compiler would be nice.

Comment: It's like asking `int *p;` to automatically allocate an integer. Not sure that would be a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialising shared\_ptr , when the object requires a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189566/initialising-shared-ptr-when-the-object-requires-a-default-constructor)

Comment: No. You'll have to make your own shared pointer class, perhaps call it `never_null_shared_ptr`, and perhaps use an underlying `std::shared_ptr` for its implementation.

Comment: @MarcoA., in general no, but I only want it for MyType, which is special.

Comment: @JonnDove then I agree with Bejamin: roll your own type.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName: No. That's not related to his problem at all, other than being about shared pointers.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName, this thread only gives the solution, I am explictly not looking for.

Comment: If you're only interested by `std::shared_ptr<YourSpecificType>`, you could specialize  `std::shared_ptr<YourSpecificType>::shared_ptr()`. But it may come to a surprise to your colleagues and increase the number of WTF/line of your codebase. Plus possibly break something else. Not A Good Idea (TM).

Comment: Just think about this a bit more: you're asking to make `shared_ptr` behave not like `shared_ptr`. That's obviously not going to be possible. It would break valid templated code which uses `shared_ptr<T>`, when `T` is your special type, which assumes that `shared_ptr` behaves as specified in the standard.

Comment: @YSC That may compile but worth addressing is that it has undefined behaviour as far as standard C++ is concerned.

Comment: if the smart pointer should never have a null value, why do you use a smartpointer in the first place? Cant you use a reference (or simply the object itself) ?

Comment: @user463035818: default constructed is different than never null. I would like to have that for pimpl idiom (with `const std::unique_ptr`)... (but as it would require definition of `pimpl`, that concept is so caducous).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a class, something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct defaulted_shared_ptr : std::shared_ptr<T>
{
    using std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr;
    defaulted_shared_ptr() : std::shared_ptr<T>(std::make_shared<T>()) {}
};
```

Then

```
defaulted_shared_ptr<Foo> foo;
```

would contain a default contructed `Foo`

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e47227911c877ea0)

Comment: can you elaborate what this line is doing using std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr;

Comment: That allow to use constructors of `shared_ptr`, so you can do `defaulted_shared_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo(42))`.